# Identifying the properties of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a control which will generate some JavaScript to write a table row to an HTML table and bind back to an IEnumerable at the server side.

Is there any way I can identify:

1. how many fields each object has
2. what these properties are called and
3. their data types?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it's called reflection. Or you can simply provide these values declaratively, like when you create GridView and you specify columns for instance...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `Type` class and the `PropertyInfo` class.